# Laravel 5 config cache issue while accessing app url inside the code

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel 5.5. Recently I have disabled ssl for my site. So I just edited .env file and set APP_URL as http://www.example.com instead of https://www.example.com. But when ever I try access url inside my code it returns with https as previously. for eg **url('sample_route')** returns **https://www.example.com/sample_route**. I have tried clearing cache and configs through artisan commands. but still getting same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try command composer dump-autoload too with cache & config clear command.

Comment: I have tried following commands

`composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize 
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear`

Issue still exist...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all php artisan commands in clearing caches?

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear    
php artisan view clear
```

Comment: yes @kapitan. also tried as suggested [here](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-clear-cache-from-route-view-config-and-all-cache-data-from-applicationexample.html)

Comment: also, try deleting the **config.php** at **bootstrap/cache** then run `php artisan config:cache` again.

Comment: how to restart laravel application?

Comment: are you able to restart apache or iis?

Comment: restarted apache too. nothing changed

Comment: can you try adding double quotes on the value of the APP_URL then run `php artisan config:cache` again

Comment: tried everything. if I change **APP_ENV** to **local**, able to clear cache and working fine...